# Database login prompt when clicked on subreports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a report and when clicked on link subreport i get Database login form.I have given all the necessary connection strings but still it asks for login info.sub reports opens in my local system but when installed in Client system i get this problem. what am i missing  or what should i do ?

Comment: How are you setting the database connection on the report?

Comment: dynDS.WriteXml("dynRep.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);                   
                    rptDynamicReport rpt = new rptDynamicReport();     
                    rpt.SetDataSource(dynDS);                    
                    DEReportViewer.ReportSource = rpt;

Answer (score 2):

I have found that when setting the database connection in code for a crystal report you need to set the connection on every single table in the report Database Definition.  You can do this like:

```
private static void SetConnectionInfo(ReportClass report, string ReportServer, string ReportDatabase)
{
    TableLogOnInfo tInfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
    ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = tInfo.ConnectionInfo;
    connectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = true;
    connectionInfo.ServerName = ReportServer;
    connectionInfo.DatabaseName = ReportDatabase;

    foreach (Table t in report.Database.Tables)
    {
        t.ApplyLogOnInfo(tInfo);
    }

    foreach (ReportClass subReport in report.Subreports)
    {
        SetConnectionInfo(subReport, ReportServer, ReportDatabase);
    }
}
```